# submit form when action="javascript:void(0)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have html step form I need to submit the form after the form passes validation and all fields are filled.I have a action controller register.php but in my html form I also have action="javascript:void(0);" so how to i submit my form action.

```html
<div class="form-bottom">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="addres 1" id="add1" name="" value="" |>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="address 2" id="add2" name="" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="city" id="city" name="" value="" |>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Home Phone" id="contact_number" name="" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I Agree<br>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Previous</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to submit your form to a URL, set `action` to that URL.

Comment: I need to capture form value & submit the form to insert values in db. i have a action "register.php" I need javascript:void(0) to validate form elements through my validation script.

Comment: Just add a submit event listener and preventDefault when error.
`document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit",function(e) { if (!validate(this)) e.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: You don't need `javascript:void(0)`; you should use event handlers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use ajax query to send data to php script.

That code insert in onsubmit function:

```
var formData = $(form_selector).serialize(); //Getting data from form
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: URL to php script, 
    data: formData, 
    success: function(data) {
        //Action if data successfully sended, it's not nessesary 
    } 
});
```

You can learn more about jQuery ajax on https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax

Comment: In my form action I have this action=" javascript:void(0);" for javascript validation